# Error saving ParseUser or ParseObject on Codenameone using parse4cn1 library

Tags: javascript, mobile, codenameone, parse4cn1

I am trying to save a parse4cn1 3.0 ParseUser or ParseObject. The object is saved on simulator, however on Java script port I receive an error. Note ParseFile save() works on both simulator & Java script port.

```
public void createTask(String userObjectId, String taskName, String taskDescription, String url) {
    try {
        ParseObject task = ParseObject.create("Task");
        task.put("userId", userObjectId);
        task.put("taskName", taskName);
        task.put("taskDescription", taskDescription);
        task.put("url", url);
        task.save();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Full stack trace from Cloud server below:

```
Executing: /home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -Dretrolambda.inputDir=/tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/tmpClasses -Dretrolambda.classpath=/tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/tmpClasses:/tmp/temp8811672204922110315.jar -Dretrolambda.outputDir=/tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/tmpClasses_retrolamda -Dretrolambda.bytecodeVersion=49 -Dretrolambda.defaultMethods=true -jar /tmp/temp7216874003515660571.jar Retrolambda 2.0.3
Bytecode version: 49 (Java 5)
Default methods:  true
Input directory:  /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/tmpClasses
Output directory: /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/tmpClasses_retrolamda
Classpath:        /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/tmpClasses:/tmp/temp8811672204922110315.jar
Executing: /home/ec2-user/javascript/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn -e clean package [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for mobi.mfactory:HelloParse:war:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ca.weblite:codename1-core:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/CodenameOne.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 24, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ca.weblite:codename1-factory:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/Factory.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 32, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ca.weblite:codename1-core-hello:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/app.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 40, column 25
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelloParse 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ HelloParse ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HelloParse ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ HelloParse ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 59 source files to /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/target/classes
[WARNING] /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/html5/Stub.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/impl/html5/Stub.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/teavm/io/BlobUtil.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/src/main/java/com/codename1/teavm/io/BlobUtil.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- teavm-maven-plugin:1.0.0-cn1-007:compile (web-client) @ HelloParse ---
[INFO] Preparing classpath for JavaScript generation
[INFO] Using the following classpath for JavaScript generation: /tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/lib/CodenameOne.jar:/tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/lib/Factory.jar:/tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/lib/app.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-classlib/1.0.0-cn1-007/teavm-classlib-1.0.0-cn1-007.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-platform/1.0.0-cn1-007/teavm-platform-1.0.0-cn1-007.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-core/1.0.0-cn1-007/teavm-core-1.0.0-cn1-007.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-interop/1.0.0-cn1-007/teavm-interop-1.0.0-cn1-007.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/carrotsearch/hppc/0.6.1/hppc-0.6.1.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-jso-apis/1.0.0-cn1-007/teavm-jso-apis-1.0.0-cn1-007.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-jso-impl/1.0.0-cn1-007/teavm-jso-impl-1.0.0-cn1-007.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7.7/rhino-1.7.7.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.4/asm-debug-all-5.0.4.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jzlib/1.1.3/jzlib-1.1.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.7/joda-time-2.7.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/teavm/teavm-jso/1.0.0-cn1-007/teavm-jso-1.0.0-cn1-007.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/mitre/dsmiley/httpproxy/smiley-http-proxy-servlet/1.6/smiley-http-proxy-servlet-1.6.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.4/httpclient-4.3.4.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/tmp/build704717599398049525xxx/target/classes
[INFO] Building JavaScript file
[INFO] Output file built with errors
[ERROR] Method java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName()Ljava/lang/String; was not found
    at com.parse4cn1.encode.ParseEncoder.encode(ParseEncoder.java:173)
    at com.parse4cn1.operation.SetFieldOperation.encode(SetFieldOperation.java:45)
    at com.parse4cn1.ParseObject.getParseData(ParseObject.java:781)
    at com.parse4cn1.ParseObject.performSave(ParseObject.java:812)
    at com.parse4cn1.ParseObject.save(ParseObject.java:682)
    at mobi.mfactory.helloparse.HelloParse.createTask(HelloParse.java:55)
    at mobi.mfactory.helloparse.HelloParse.start(HelloParse.java:242)
    at com.codename1.impl.html5.Stub.run(Stub.java:87)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.callSerially(Display.java:772)
    at com.codename1.impl.html5.Stub.main(Stub.java:75)
[INFO] Debug information successfully written
[INFO] Source maps successfully written
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.183 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-19T14:40:18+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/893M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:1.0.0-cn1-007:compile (web-client) on project HelloParse: Build error -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:1.0.0-cn1-007:compile (web-client) on project HelloParse: Build error
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Build error
    at org.teavm.maven.TeaVMCompileMojo.execute(TeaVMCompileMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Currently 'stopOnErrors' is on.  With this enabled, even build warnings will cause the build to fail. 
Try adding the 'javascript.stopOnErrors=false' build hint and see if it builds.  
WARNING: switching stopOnErrors off may result in runtime errors, if the warnings actually fall in the execution path of the app.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `getCanonicalName()` is missing from the JavaScript port. I'm not sure if this is something we should fix in the JavaScript port or add as a pull request to parse4cn1. This doesn't seem to be essential for parse [based on this search](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getCanonicalName).

Since the method is deprecated to begin with and not recommended I'm sure it can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Forking and Updating the parse4cn1 lib ended up being the quicker temporary solution. I remove every occurrence of `getCanonicalName()`, rebuilt the cn1lib and re-submitted the Java script port build.

Build successful and the save() method works now. Thanks.

parsecn1 cn1lib will need to be updated with this fix.